# Setting new data('key', object) on element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using `draggable`, `droppable`, and `resizable` in a project. When an element has been dragged to a specific location, it is appended to a `div` and assigned specific `data` attributes using `$('.selector').data("index", {key: value})` method.

I am trying to update the data after the element is resized. I can get data, yet I cannot seem to set or update existing data.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/18erqbqv/23/

Data Added in `drop` function:

```
var pos = ui.position;
var $obj = ui.helper.clone();
var c = $(".dropped").length;

$obj.data("obj", {
  id: c,
  label: $obj.text(),
  top: pos.top,
  left: pos.left,
  width: $obj.width(),
  height: $obj.height(),
  layer: $obj.zIndex() - 1000
});

$obj.appendTo(".droppable");
```

Attempt to update in `stop` of resizable:

```
var self = $(this);

self.resizable({
  handles: "ne, nw, se, sw",
  grid: $(".grid").data("size"),
  ghost: true,
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    console.log("Resize Stopped on ID: " + $(this).data("obj").id);
    $(this).data("obj").width = ui.size.width;
    $(this).data("obj").height = ui.size.height;
  }
});

console.log(self.data());
```

The idea is that a user drags an element to the droppable area. Once dropped, they can then click it to select the element, making it draggable and resizable. Once resize is stopped, I want to update the data. When the user next clicks on the element, I should see the new data in console.

It does not look like the data is being updated.

Other methods I have tried:

```
$(this).data("obj", {
  width: ui.size.width,
  height: ui.size.height
});

self.data("obj", {
  width: ui.size.width,
  height: ui.size.height
});
```

Thanks in advance!